# In Java, create a generic parsed string cache (multiple resulting types)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a generic parsed string cache to prevent rebuilding the same object over and over. Essentially, what I'm building is something like the following:

```
public class ParsedStringCache {

    // static Map<Pair<String, Parser<T>>, T> _cache
    //      = new HashMap<Pair<String, Parser<T>>, T>();

    public interface StringParser<T> {
        public T parseString(String stringToParse);
    }

    public static <T> T getParsedObject(String stringToParse, Parser<T> parser) {
        return parser.parseString(stringToParse);
    }
}
```

This works fine until I try to actually cache the results, such as by using something similar to the commented out hashmap in the code above, which would essentially memoize the result of getParsedObject. Is there a reasonably simple way to do this that avoids casting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the cache part of the parser. I'm sure you'll run into some kind of compile error that you'll need to workaround, but here's the basics of what I would do.

```
import java.util.*;
abstract class Parser<T> {

    private Map<String,T> cache = new HashMap<String,T>();

    public final T parseString(String str) {
        T result = cache.get(str);
        if(result == null) {
            result = parseString0(str);
            cache.put(str,result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract T parseString0(String str);

}

public class IntParser extends Parser<Integer> {

    protected Integer parseString0(String str) {
        return Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
    }

}

public class LongParser extends Parser<Long> {

    protected Long parseString0(String str) {
        return Long.parseLong(str.trim());
    }

}

class ParserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parser<Integer> intParse = new IntParser();
        Parser<Long> longParse = new LongParser();

        Long long1 = longParse.parseString("10000");
        Long long2 = longParse.parseString("20000");
        Long long3 = longParse.parseString("30000");
        Long equalLong = longParse.parseString("20000"); // repeat long2
        Long fakeLong = new LongParser().parseString("20000"); // repeated with fake
        System.out.println("Expecting true: " + (long2 == equalLong));
        System.out.println("Expecting false: " + (fakeLong == equalLong));
    }
}

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac Parser.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac IntParser.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac LongParser.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac ParserTest.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java ParserTest
Expecting true: true
Expecting false: false
```

I would keep them managed how they are, but add methods to gather information and report to a central manager. Obviously you'll need to add some more methods to the parser to keep track of the cache. Or (and this is probably a better idea) you could consolidate the cache logic into a Cache class, and let the manager track those caches.

By doing it this way you allow the cache itself to determine how it trims its information. It could be by oldest, it could be by size, it could be all kinds of criteria. Perhaps it has user information and you want your paid users to stay in the cache more.

```
import java.util.*;
class ParserCacheManager {

    private Set<Parser<?>> parsers = new HashSet<Parser<?>>();

    public void addParser(Parser<?> p) { parsers.add(p); }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for(Parser<?> p : parsers) size += p.cacheSize();
        return size;
    }

    public void trimToSize(int maxSize) {
        while(size() > maxSize) {
            Parser<?> p = largestParser();
            p.trimToPercent(0.90);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This would be better perhaps with a set sorted by
     * size, or something like that. But this works for example.
     */
    private Parser<?> largestParser() {
        Parser<?> largest = null;
        for(Parser<?> p : parsers) {
            if(largest == null || p.size() > largest.size())
                largest = p;
        }
        return largest;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to store these objects together in a central cache, where I can more easily track how big the cache is and evict stale entries if the cache gets too big.

Comment: I have added an example cache manager class that helps address that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing this as an exercise, consider using Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html)  (or the more general [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html)) for this task. It will handle all concurrency and expiration under the hood and is easily and fluently configurable:

```
Cache<String, T> parsedObjectCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, T>() {
         public T load(String str) throws MyParseException {
           return parse(str); //called either on or from inside a Parser<T>
         }
       });
```

If you want a centralized cache, you would need to compose a custom key class that wrapped references to the `String` and `Parser<?>` and overrode hashcode/equals.

However, you're probably better off implementing a separate `Cache<String, T>` for each parser since type information will be lost trying to store everything in the same `Collection`.

A compromise would be to keep a master `Map<Parser<?>, Cache<String, ?>>` which you could use to look up each `Cache` based on the `Parser` (or alternatively use each `Class<?>` of `T` as the key). However you're still losing generic type information this way and casting would be necessary.

You might consider [@glowcoder's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654276/in-java-create-a-generic-parsed-string-cache-multiple-resulting-types/7654398#7654398) and integrate a `Cache<String, T>` into each `Parser<T>`. This seems a reasonable way to maintain generic type information without casting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make ParserStringCache generic and you cannot use arbitrary generic parameter on a static class variable, it has to be a non-static member.

```
public class ParsedStringCache< T > {

    Map<Pair<String, Parser<T>>, T> _cache =
      new HashMap<Pair<String, Parser<T>>, T>();
}
```

Comment: This won't let you cache `Parser<Obj1>` and `Parser<Obj2>` in the same map though.